# Error downloading textblob certificate verify failed

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, textblob

I am running Python 2.7 on a Macbook Air 10.5 Yosemite. I am running into this problem with installing textblob. What to do?

```
$ pip install -U textblob //no errors
$ python -m textblob.download_corpora
[nltk_data] Error loading brown: <urlopen error [SSL:
[nltk_data]dsaffdsa     CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed
[nltk_data]     (_ssl.c:661)>
[nltk_data] Error loading punkt: <urlopen error [SSL:
[nltk_data]     CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed
[nltk_data]     (_ssl.c:661)>
[nltk_data] Error loading wordnet: <urlopen error [SSL:
[nltk_data]     CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed
[nltk_data]     (_ssl.c:661)>
[nltk_data] Error loading averaged_perceptron_tagger: <urlopen error
[nltk_data]     [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify
[nltk_data]     failed (_ssl.c:661)>
[nltk_data] Error loading conll2000: <urlopen error [SSL:
[nltk_data]     CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed
[nltk_data]     (_ssl.c:661)>
[nltk_data] Error loading movie_reviews: <urlopen error [SSL:
[nltk_data]     CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed
[nltk_data]     (_ssl.c:661)>
Finished.
```

Comment: This may prove useful, albeit for linux. https://access.redhat.com/articles/2039753

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem and found the solution posted here: [NLTK download SSL: Certificate verify failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916452/nltk-download-ssl-certificate-verify-failed)

Try downloading Python 3.6 and running the `/Applications/Python\ 3.6/Install\ Certificates.command`.