# upload failed: .\<filename.sql> to s3://<bucket-name>/<filename.sql> [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3

I am trying to copy .sql file to amazon s3. But I keep getting this error message after applying following command in Command Prompt:

`aws s3 cp <filename.sql> s3://<bucket-name>`

error message is:

`upload failed: .\<filename.sql> to s3://bucket-name/<filename.sql> [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)`

Can anyone please walk through this issue? I'm using Windows 10 OS.

Comment: You can try below link to see if it helps you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916452/nltk-download-ssl-certificate-verify-failed

Comment: @TheGameiswar that link will be use for those who are using nltk or punkt library and error is also different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all try to run the same CLI command with key --no-verify-ssl

If it won't work then next:

Do you have the AWS_CA_BUNDLE env var set?
Do you have certifi installed in your python env? (pip list | grep certifi)

$ echo $AWS_CA_BUNDLE

$ export | grep AWS_CA_BUNDLE
$ pip list | grep certifi
certifi (2015.9.6.2)

Certifi downgrade or removing should fix the problem.

Comment: --no-verify-ssl is worked but also its shows me following warning InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. Thanks @Alex