# Can someone help me with error in using nltk word_tokenize function?

Tags: python, nltk

I have nltk installed on my mac. Below is my simple code to use nltk word_tokenize function. And I'm getting this error. Please advise!

```
import nltk

sentence = "I kN2ow Y1Ou."

s = sentence.lower()
words = nltk.word_tokenize(s)

print(words)
```

Error:

```
**********************************************************************
  Resource punkt not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  >>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('punkt')
  
  For more information see: https://www.nltk.org/data.html

  Attempted to load tokenizers/punkt/PY3/english.pickle

  Searched in:
    - '/Users/moeheinag/nltk_data'
    - '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/nltk_data'
    - '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/share/nltk_data'
    - '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
    - ''
**********************************************************************
```

So I just ran in terminal:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
```

And received this errors:

```
[nltk_data] Error loading punkt: <urlopen error [SSL:
[nltk_data]     CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed:
[nltk_data]     unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1124)>
False
```

Comment: the error literally tells you exactly what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the `punkt` module as stated

Open `Terminal` on your mac , execute - `python` , then the below commands

`nltk` uses pre-trained , word and sentence tokenizers , which needs to be downloaded seperately

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download('punkt')
```

If in case the download fails , use below , [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916452/nltk-download-ssl-certificate-verify-failed)

```
import nltk
import ssl

try:
    _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
    pass
else:
    ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context

nltk.download()
```

Comment: So I just did this and I got some errors. I'll revise my original post to include it.

Comment: I have revised it.