# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED using Watson Streaming STT

Tags: python, python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, streaming, ibm-watson

I watched [a tutorial](https://youtu.be/YCyuZM454_I) on YouTube on how to do **live** speech to text and I was told to clone [this repository](https://github.com/IBM/watson-streaming-stt). I edited the code a bit to include the `APIKEY` and `url` in the code without the need to have a `.cfg` file. But I get the following error:
`[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)`

This is my code:

```
#
# Copyright 2016 IBM
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may
# not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain
# a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
# WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
# License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.

import argparse
import base64
import json
import threading
import time

import pyaudio
import websocket
from websocket._abnf import ABNF

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
# Even if your default input is multi channel (like a webcam mic),
# it's really important to only record 1 channel, as the STT service
# does not do anything useful with stereo. You get a lot of "hmmm"
# back.
CHANNELS = 1
# Rate is important, nothing works without it. This is a pretty
# standard default. If you have an audio device that requires
# something different, change this.
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
FINALS = []
LAST = None

REGION_MAP = {
    'us-east': 'gateway-wdc.watsonplatform.net',
    'us-south': 'stream.watsonplatform.net',
    'eu-gb': 'stream.watsonplatform.net',
    'eu-de': 'stream-fra.watsonplatform.net',
    'au-syd': 'gateway-syd.watsonplatform.net',
    'jp-tok': 'gateway-syd.watsonplatform.net',
}


def read_audio(ws, timeout):
    """Read audio and sent it to the websocket port.

    This uses pyaudio to read from a device in chunks and send these
    over the websocket wire.

    """
    global RATE
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    # NOTE(sdague): if you don't seem to be getting anything off of
    # this you might need to specify:
    #
    #    input_device_index=N,
    #
    # Where N is an int. You'll need to do a dump of your input
    # devices to figure out which one you want.
    RATE = int(p.get_default_input_device_info()['defaultSampleRate'])
    stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                    channels=CHANNELS,
                    rate=RATE,
                    input=True,
                    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

    print("* recording")
    rec = timeout or RECORD_SECONDS

    for _ in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * rec)):
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        # print("Sending packet... %d" % i)
        # NOTE(sdague): we're sending raw binary in the stream, we
        # need to indicate that otherwise the stream service
        # interprets this as text control messages.
        ws.send(data, ABNF.OPCODE_BINARY)

    # Disconnect the audio stream
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    print("* done recording")

    # In order to get a final response from STT we send a stop, this
    # will force a final=True return message.
    data = {"action": "stop"}
    ws.send(json.dumps(data).encode('utf8'))
    # ... which we need to wait for before we shutdown the websocket
    time.sleep(1)
    ws.close()

    # ... and kill the audio device
    p.terminate()


def on_message(self, msg):
    """Print whatever messages come in.

    While we are processing any non trivial stream of speech Watson
    will start chunking results into bits of transcripts that it
    considers "final", and start on a new stretch. It's not always
    clear why it does this. However, it means that as we are
    processing text, any time we see a final chunk, we need to save it
    off for later.
    """
    global LAST
    data = json.loads(msg)
    if "results" in data:
        if data["results"][0]["final"]:
            FINALS.append(data)
            LAST = None
        else:
            LAST = data
        # This prints out the current fragment that we are working on
        print(data['results'][0]['alternatives'][0]['transcript'])


def on_error(self, error):
    """Print any errors."""
    print(error)


def on_close(ws):
    """Upon close, print the complete and final transcript."""
    global LAST
    if LAST:
        FINALS.append(LAST)
    transcript = "".join([x['results'][0]['alternatives'][0]['transcript']
                          for x in FINALS])
    print(transcript)


def on_open(ws):
    """Triggered as soon a we have an active connection."""
    args = ws.args
    data = {
        "action": "start",
        # this means we get to send it straight raw sampling
        "content-type": "audio/l16;rate=%d" % RATE,
        "continuous": True,
        "interim_results": True,
        # "inactivity_timeout": 5, # in order to use this effectively
        # you need other tests to handle what happens if the socket is
        # closed by the server.
        "word_confidence": True,
        "timestamps": True,
        "max_alternatives": 3
    }

    # Send the initial control message which sets expectations for the
    # binary stream that follows:
    ws.send(json.dumps(data).encode('utf8'))
    # Spin off a dedicated thread where we are going to read and
    # stream out audio.
    threading.Thread(target=read_audio,
                     args=(ws, args.timeout)).start()

def get_url():
    # See
    # https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/speech-to-text/websockets.html#websockets
    # for details on which endpoints are for each region.
    region = 'eu-gb'
    host = REGION_MAP[region]
    return ("wss://{}/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize"
           "?model=en-US_BroadbandModel").format(host)

def get_auth():
    return ("apikey", 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')


def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Transcribe Watson text in real time')
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--timeout', type=int, default=5)
    # parser.add_argument('-d', '--device')
    # parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', action='store_true')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args


def main():
    # Connect to websocket interfaces
    headers = {}
    userpass = ":".join(get_auth())
    headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + base64.b64encode(
        userpass.encode()).decode()
    url = get_url()

    # If you really want to see everything going across the wire,
    # uncomment this. However realize the trace is going to also do
    # things like dump the binary sound packets in text in the
    # console.
    #
    # websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(url,
                                header=headers,
                                on_message=on_message,
                                on_error=on_error,
                                on_close=on_close)
    ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.args = parse_args()
    # This gives control over the WebSocketApp. This is a blocking
    # call, so it won't return until the ws.close() gets called (after
    # 6 seconds in the dedicated thread).
    ws.run_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

By the way, I'm on Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I just needed to run

```
/Applications/Python\ 3.9/Install\ Certificates.command
```

on Mac and then change the URL, because the code was outdated.

The original URL was:

```
stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize
```

I changed it to:

```
api.eu-gb.text-to-speech.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/xxxxxxxxxx/v1/synthesize
```

That new URL can be found in your IBM Cloud Dashboard.

Comment: hey can you show me all integral code?

Answer (score 0):

Well there is a quick way to bypass this. Before your code add

```
import ssl

try:
    _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
    pass
else:
    ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context
```

[Reference Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916452/nltk-download-ssl-certificate-verify-failed)

Comment: But they mentioned this `bash /Applications/Python 3.6/Install Certificates.command`

Comment: That command worked, but now I get this other error: `Handshake status 403 Forbidden`